# Sufficient condition for irreducibility of homogeneous polynomial (Exercise I. 5.9 in Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

From Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry. Exercise I. 5.9 states:

> Let $f\in k[x,y,z]$ be a homogeneous polynomial, let $Z(f)\subseteq \mathbf{P}^2$ be the algebraic set defined by $f$, and suppose that for every $P\ \in Z(f)$, at least one of $(\partial f /\partial x)(P)$, $(\partial f /\partial y)(P)$, $(\partial f /\partial z)(P)$ is nonzero. Show that $f$ is irreducible.

Hartshorne gives a hint to use Exercise I. 3.7., which states,

> If $Y \in \mathbf{P}^n$ is a projective variety of dimension $\geq 1$,  and if $H$ is a hypersurface, then $Y \cap H \neq \emptyset$.

I tried the following:

Suppose that $\forall P \in Z(f)$, $(\partial f /\partial x)(P)$, $(\partial f /\partial y)(P)$, $(\partial f /\partial z)(P)$ are not all zero. This means that $Z(f) \cap Z(f_x, f_y, f_z) = \emptyset$. By exercise 3.7, $Y \cap H \neq \emptyset$ for $Y$ a variety and $H$ a a hypersurface (i.e., the zero set of a single irreducible polynomial). If $A$ is any algebraic set, then $A$ decomposes into irreducible components,

$A=W_1 \cup \dots \cup W_q$.

So $A \cap H=(W_1 \cup \dots \cup W_q) \cap H = [W_1 \cap H]\cup\dots\cup[W_q \cap H]$. By exercise 3.7, each $[W_i \cap H] \neq \emptyset$, hence $A \cap H \neq \emptyset$.

So, if $Z(f) \cap Z(f_x,f_y,f_z)=\emptyset$, then since $Z(f_x,f_y,f_z)$ is an algebraic set, $Z(f)$ cannot be a hypersurface. That is, $f$ cannot be irreducible.

Obviously this is very wrong, but even in such a simple argument I cannot pinpoint why. Please help. I am not looking for unrelated correct solutions to this exercise. I just want to understand the mistake in the above argument. Thank you.

Edit: By $f_x$ I mean $\partial f / \partial x$, the polynomial which is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathcal{Z}(f_x, f_y,f_z)$ must have dimension at least one to apply the result from the Exercise I.3.7. Have you checked if this is true?

You will find that in fact this is not the case! $\mathcal{Z}(f_x, f_y,f_z)$ is $0$-dimensional!

**Later edit:** To see that $\mathcal{Z}(f_x, f_y,f_z)$ has dimension $0$ is very easy. Assume the contrary. Since $\mathcal{Z}(f)$ is an hypersurface (not necessarily irreducible) in $\mathbb{P}^2$, then using the Exercise I.3.7 we would get $\mathcal{Z}(f) \cap \mathcal{Z}(f_x, f_y,f_z) \neq \emptyset$, which is a contradiction.

I think it is a good idea to have a look at the Projective dimension theorem (Theorem I.7.2) from Hartshorne to see the general phenomena (the Exercise I.3.7 is just a particular case of this theorem).

**Later edit #2** Write $f = p_1^{\alpha_1} \ldots p_l^{\alpha_l}$ with $p_i$ irreducible polynomials. Then
$$\mathcal{Z}(f) = \bigcup_{i=1}^l \mathcal{Z}(p_i)$$
Now, $\mathcal{Z}(p_i)$ are hypersurfaces as in the definition of Hartshorne. Then, working in the assumption that $\text{dim}(\mathcal{Z}(f_x, f_y,f_z)) \ge 1$ and applying Exercise I.3.7 we get that for any $i$
$$\mathcal{Z}(p_i) \cap \mathcal{Z}(f_x, f_y,f_z) \neq \emptyset$$
and hence, in particular
$$\mathcal{Z}(f) \cap \mathcal{Z}(f_x, f_y,f_z) \neq \emptyset$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: How would I prove it is 0-dimensional? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By exercise I.3.7 :))

Comment: I'm currently looking at Theorem I. 7.2, but I am wondering why we should assume that $Z(f)$ is a hypersurface, when we do not already know that $f$ is irreducible? (Hartshorne defined a hypersurface as the zero set of an irreducible polynomial.) Does assuming dim$Z(f_x, f_y, f_z) >0$ imply $Z(f)$ is a hypersurface?

Comment: That's why I said in the brackets that for me a hypersurface is not necessarily irreducible! It is just the zero set of a single polynomial. Can you see why I can still use Exercise I.3.7 in this situation?

Comment: $Z(f) \cap Z(f_x, f_y, f_z)$ is the intersection of two algebraic sets, so I guess then the exercise would imply that it is nonempty. But I don't see why this implies $Z(f_x, f_y, f_z)$ has dimension 0.

Comment: See the second edit. Don't forget that you have observed that $\mathcal{Z}(f) \cap \mathcal{Z}(f_x. f_y, f_z)$ should be the empty set.

Comment: Oh, at first I didn't see why it would be a contradiction. But now I realize that in this answer we are working under the hypothesis of the exercise. It is perfectly clear now. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 3):

Just because $Z(f)\cap Z(f_x,  f_y, f_z)\neq \phi$ does not imply that $Z(f)$ is not irreducible.

What we have is that the closure of $Z(f)\setminus Z(f_x, f_y, f_z)$ is the whole space $Z(f)$.

So we have $Z(f)= X_1\cup X_2$ where $X_1=Z(f)\setminus Z(f_x, f_y, f_z)$, $X_2=\overline{Z(f)\cap X_1}$. $X_1, X_2$ are both closed but $X_2=Z(f)$ so it doesn't contradict it being irreducible.

The point is that the intersection of the two curves will be points. But the closure of its complement in $Z(f)$ just yields the curve back.

Comment: I was trying to show that $f$ is irreducible as a polynomial, not $Z(f)$ is irreducible as an algebraic set. Can you maybe explain in more detail how this shows the original argument is incorrect?

Comment: If $f$ is not irreducible and say $f=gh$, then $Z(f)=Z(g)\cup Z(h)$ and so it won't be irreducible in the topological sense.